# Conversion of data

Tags: python, linux, awk

I have data in the following format:

Input data:

```
 <http://A> <http://code.google.com/p/ldspider/ns#headerInfo> _:H  <id_0> .
<id_0> <C> <http://A>  <id_1> .
 _:H <http://www.w3.org/2006/http#responseCode> "200"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer>  <id_2> .
<id_2> <C> <http://A>  <id_3> .
 _:H <http://www.w3.org/2006/http#date> "Mon, 23 Apr 2012 13:49:27 GMT"  <id_4> .
<id_4> <C> <http://A>  <id_5> .
 _:H <http://www.w3.org/2006/http#content-type> "application/rdf+xml; charset=UTF-8"  <id_6> .
```

I want to convert this data into the following form:

Output data:

```
 #@ <id_0>
 <http://A> <http://code.google.com/p/ldspider/ns#headerInfo> _:H  .
 #@ <id_1> 
 <id_0> <C> <http://A> .
 #@ <id_2>
 _:H <http://www.w3.org/2006/http#responseCode> "200"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer> .
 #@ <id_3>
 <id_2> <C> <http://A> .
 #@ <id_4>
 _:H <http://www.w3.org/2006/http#date> "Mon, 23 Apr 2012 13:49:27 GMT" .
 #@ <id_5>
 <id_4> <C> <http://A> .
 #@ <id_6>
 _:H <http://www.w3.org/2006/http#content-type> "application/rdf+xml; charset=UTF-8" .
```

I know I can easily do this using c++ by parsing file but can I also do the same using linux commands like awk, etc. or using python? Here I want the last column from Input data to appear as first row with #@ in Output data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that some of the data does not look exactly tabular, I'd treat it as plain text and use regexes to isolate the last two fields manually, in order to avoid trimming of meaningful whitespaces.

With GNU sed, this might look as follows:

```
sed -r 's/^(.*\S)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)$/#@ \2\n\1 \3/' filename
```

`\s` and `\S` are a GNU extension matching whitespace and everything but whitespace, respectively; the rest is just splitting the line into capturing groups and reassembling it before printing. Note that this removes excess whitespace between the third-to-last field and the last field (the `.` at the end of the lines). Going by your example output, this appears to be what you want.

If whitespace trimming is not a worry, then

```
awk '{ print "#@ " $(NF - 1); $(NF - 1) = $NF; --NF; print }' filename
```

seems like a sane way to do it in (g|m)awk.